# Samsung WiTu (i900/Omnia) mobile phone program

Tags: c#, compact-framework, mobile

I want to write a simple C# program that will be activated on incoming call to display a text on the phone screen. Just a simple C# program activated by an incoming call.
Any ideas how I can get started?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific about what you need help with.

Comment: I want to write a simple C# program that will be activated on incoming call to display a text on the phone screen.
Just that.

Comment: Please take some initiative and provide at least your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to ask on Modaco or xda-forums. They have a very big Windows Mobile community there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://www.developer.com/ws/pc/article.php/3547381/Your-Windows-Mobile-50-Applications-Can-Monitor-Clients-and-Respond-to-Change.htm

Using the System State and Notification Broker API you can register an event that will fire when a state changes, and one of the states you can monitor is incoming call.